# aplay -l says no soundcards found; alsaconf says no supported cords; yet /proc/asound contains cards

Tags: 10.04, nvidia, hdmi, alsa

I am trying to get HDMI output using a Gainward Nvidia 210 512 MB on Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx.

I have upgraded alsa-driver, alsa-lib and alsa-utils to 1.0.24 by building from source, thanks to [this blog post](http://duopetalflower.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/alsa-1024-in-ubuntu-1010.html).

After i use `aplay -l` on terminal, it says:

```
user@box:~$ lspci | grep Audio
00:05.0 Audio device: nVidia Corporation MCP61 High Definition Audio (rev a2)
01:09.0 Multimedia video controller: Conexant Systems, Inc. CX23880/1/2/3 PCI Video and Audio Decoder (rev 05)
01:09.2 Multimedia controller: Conexant Systems, Inc. CX23880/1/2/3 PCI Video and Audio Decoder [MPEG Port] (rev 05)
01:09.4 Multimedia controller: Conexant Systems, Inc. CX23880/1/2/3 PCI Video and Audio Decoder [IR Port] (rev 05)
02:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)


user@box:~$ cat /proc/asound/version
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.24.
Compiled on Sep 15 2012 for kernel 2.6.32-42-generic (SMP).


user@box:~$ ls /proc/asound`
card0  cards    hwdep    NVidia    oss  seq     version
card1  devices  modules  NVidia_1  pcm  timers


user@box:~$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:240: no soundcards found...


user@box:~$ sudo /sbin/alsa-utils start
 * Setting up ALSA...
 * warning: 'alsactl restore' failed with error message 'alsactl: set_control:1403:
Cannot write control '2:0:0:IEC958 Playback Default:0' : Operation not permitted'...
amixer: Invalid command!
...done.
```

Any help appreciated.

PS my video card is connected only through the PCI-E slot. I assume there is no extra audio connection required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.0.24 is quite old; you should at least use the 1.0.25 driver package.

Your aplay/amixer problems sound as if you have permission problems. Check that your user is in a group that has access to the device nodes in /dev/snd/.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, as it's probably the right sort of suggestion. I cured it in the end by simply moving to 12.04LTS, which brought me kicking and screaming into the present.